# how to use mask in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to find one value of one refnum whose number is like "00627987800001" so when i am writing the query I am facing two issue.

1.I need the full number including the initial Zeros.

2.Another concern is I need to use make the number as - separated like 0062-7987-800-001

and my query is below.

```
SELECT nvl(to_char((SELECT lr.location_refnum_value
                     FROM location_refnum lr,
                          servprov        sr,
                          location        loc,
                          shipment        sh
                    WHERE sh.servprov_gid = sr.servprov_gid
                      AND sr.servprov_gid = loc.location_gid
                      AND loc.location_gid = lr.location_gid
                      AND lr.location_refnum_qual_gid = 'ULA.UL_CPF'
                      AND sh.shipment_gid = :p_shipment_id),
                   '999999999999'),
           '-')
  FROM dual
```

Comment: SELECT NVL (TO_CHAR((SELECT LR.LOCATION_REFNUM_VALUE FROM LOCATION_REFNUM LR , SERVPROV SR, LOCATION LOC , SHIPMENT SH
WHERE SH.SERVPROV_GID = SR.SERVPROV_GID
AND SR.SERVPROV_GID = LOC.LOCATION_GID
AND LOC.LOCATION_GID = LR.LOCATION_GID
AND LR.LOCATION_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULA.UL_CPF'
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID = :P_SHIPMENT_ID),'999999999999'),'-') FROM DUAL

Answer (score 0):

```
select  regexp_replace (to_char (627987800001,'FM00000000000000'),'(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})','\1-\2-\3-\4')

from    dual
;
```

---

... and by all means, use ANSI/ISO JOINs

```
select  regexp_replace 
        (
            to_char (lr.location_refnum_value,'FM00000000000000')
           ,'(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{3})'
           ,'\1-\2-\3-\4'
        ) 

from            location_refnum         lr

        join    location                loc

        on      loc.location_gid    = 
                lr.location_gid

        join    servprov                sr 

        on      sr.servprov_gid     =
                loc.location_gid

        join    shipment                sh

        on      sh.servprov_gid     = 
                sr.servprov_gid

where   lr.location_refnum_qual_gid = 'ULA.UL_CPF'
    and sh.shipment_gid             = :p_shipment_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use To_number function to convert the string into corresponding "number" value to compare further in your `where` condition.
2. you can use combination of `instr` and `substr` function to append the desired char "-" in between the numbers given.

**Edit**

2. alternatively you can use the Regular expression as suggested by Dudu in his answer.